# How to handle client disconnect in Socket Programming?

Tags: c#, sockets, network-programming

I have written a server side code using Sockets, Its working fine but have one problem I don't know how to handle this scenario: if client just closes application without sending Disconnect request, my server side program crashes. What do I need to do to avoid this? Please guide me I am new to Socket programming.

```
private void OnReceive(IAsyncResult result)
{
    try
    {
        Socket clientSocket = (Socket)result.AsyncState;
        clientSocket.EndReceive(result);

        command = responseMessage = string.Empty;
        command = ByteToString(receviedData);
        receviedData = new byte[30];

        if (command=="Connect")
        {
            ClientInfo clientInfo = new ClientInfo();
            clientInfo.socket = clientSocket;
            clientInfo.IP = clientSocket.RemoteEndPoint.ToString();
            connectedClients.Add(clientInfo);
            responseMessage = "Connection established...";
        }
        else if (command=="Disconnect")
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < connectedClients.Count; i++)
            {
                if (connectedClients[i].socket == clientSocket)
                {
                    connectedClients.RemoveAt(i);
                    break;
                }
            }
            clientSocket.Close();
        }
        else
        {
            responseMessage = "Error";
        }

        byte[] responseStatus = StringToByte(responseMessage);
        for (int i = 0; i < connectedClients.Count; i++)
        {
            if (connectedClients[i].socket==clientSocket)
            {
                connectedClients[i].socket.BeginSend(responseStatus, 0, responseStatus.Length,SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(OnSend), connectedClients[i].socket);
                break;
            }
        }

    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
      throw new Exception(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: you will need to try/catch the corresponding exception: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/0yd65esw(v=vs.110).aspx 
As you seem new to stack overflow, please make sure to read the FAQ section. http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: please post the code where you get the exception.

Comment: I am using this, but the whole server side application is crashing because of this and failed to respond to other clients as well

Comment: i have posted the code @ErenErsönmez

Comment: @user1941098 Well you're just re-throwing the exception. You need to just ignore it (but possibly do other things like removing the client object from connectedClients).

Comment: @user1941098 I started an answer and will try to help you. Can you please provide the type/declaration of `connectedClients`? Is it `List<ClientInfo>`?

Comment: struct ClientInfo
    {
        public Socket socket;//Socket of the client
        public string IP; 
    }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your application crashes, because you throw an exception in the `catch` block of your method.

If you don't want your application to crash, you need to remove the `throw new Exception(ex.Message);` line from the `catch` block. 
Replace it with code that handles the error and gracefully restores your application to a safe state. From reading your code, this should be done by removing the `clientSocket` from `connectedClients`

Secondly, it is better to just use `throw;` instead of `throw new Exception(ex.Message);`. `throw;` will re-throw the original exception object and thus preserve the stack trace and other vital information that helps in debugging your software.
Using `new Exception("Message")` will create a completely new exception object with the current stack trace.

```
private void OnReceive(IAsyncResult result)
{
    try
    {
        Socket clientSocket = (Socket)result.AsyncState;
        clientSocket.EndReceive(result);

        command = responseMessage = string.Empty;
        command = ByteToString(receviedData);
        receviedData = new byte[30];

        if (command=="Connect")
        {
            ClientInfo clientInfo = new ClientInfo() {
               socket = clientSocket,
               IP = clientSocket.RemoteEndPoint.ToString(),
               }; 
            connectedClients.Add(clientInfo);
            responseMessage = "Connection established...";
        }
        else if (command=="Disconnect")
        {
            removeClientInfo(clientSocket);
            clientSocket.Close();
        }
        else
        {
            responseMessage = "Error";
        }

        byte[] responseStatus = StringToByte(responseMessage);
        for (int i = 0; i < connectedClients.Count; i++)
        {
            if (connectedClients[i].socket==clientSocket)
            {
                connectedClients[i].socket.BeginSend(responseStatus, 0, responseStatus.Length,SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(OnSend), connectedClients[i].socket);
                break;
            }
        }

    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
      // add error handling and gracefully recover
      // caution: The way done here, might work, but it smells :-/
      removeClientInfo((Socket)result.AsyncState);
      ((Socket)result.AsyncState).Close();
    }
}

/// removes the client info from the connectedClients enumerable
private void removeClientInfo(Socket socket)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < connectedClients.Count; i++)
    {
        if (connectedClients[i].socket == socket)
        {
            connectedClients.RemoveAt(i);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: is there any better approach to this? any best practice to handle this?

Comment: What part of my answer are you refering to? IMHO both parts are *best practice*.

Comment: clientSocket is not in the scope of catch block! how can i handle remove or closing connection of client in Catch block?

Comment: which approach is better yours or Eren Ersönmez? which one suites scaleable application?

Comment: @user1941098 Eren and I both use the same approach (handling the error correctly in the `catch` block). He additionally pointed out that you need to check the return value of `EndReceive`, I made some changes to the code to enhance readability. **tl;dr: Use all of it.** 
Regarding "scaleable applications": this is not your problem at the moment. Your problem is to **make it work**. Care about performance once your code works, is correct and is readable. No sooner

Comment: its working fine now! but now please tell me about speed & performance of this method! how can it improve it! point me to any good resource from where i can learn best practices for socket programming.

Answer (score 1):

You are throwing a new exception inside the `catch` block, which doesn't make much sense unless you're doing some logging or similar. Change the catch block like:

```
catch(SocketException)
{ 
}
```

Also, you should check the number of bytes read returned from `EndReceive`. If you receive zero bytes, that means the client has shutdown the connection:

```
int numReceived = clientSocket.EndReceive(result);
if(numReceived == 0)
{
    //client has shutdown the connection
}
```

Comment: is there any difference between EndReceive and Receive methods?

Comment: of course they are different. They are related to asynchronous sockets vs synchronous respectively.